# CSS3 background-image between <li> in a vertical list

Tags: html, css

I have list of `#menu` `<li>`'s like this:

```
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>item 3</a></li>
    <li><a>item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and I want to add a image after each li element and one above the whole list using the `background-image: url('../img/menu_divider.png');` property. Also I want to keep the size of the image even if it is replaced with a retina image in a `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after trying different stuff I found that I could do something like this:

```
#menu ul > li {
  background: url('../img/menu_divider.png') no-repeat bottom left;

  -webkit-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Firefox */
  -ms-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Opera */
  background-size: <image width> auto; /* CSS3 */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  #menu ul > li {
    background-image: url('../img/menu_divider@2x.png');
  }
}
```

And add this to add an image above the whole list:

```
#menu ul {
  background: url('../img/menu_divider.png') no-repeat top left;

  -webkit-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Firefox */
  -ms-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-background-size: <image width> auto; /* Opera */
  background-size: <image width> auto; /* CSS3 */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  #menu ul {
    background-image: url('../img/menu_divider@2x.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: what is with all this `x-background-size`? The top CSS could be just one line.

Comment: I needed to cover many browser versions and here is an explanation of why I use the browser specific background-size properties (http://www.quackit.com/css/css3/properties/css_background-size.cfm):
"[...] For maximum browser compatibility many web developers add browser-specific properties by using extensions such as -webkit- for Safari and Google Chrome, -ms- for Internet Explorer, -moz- for Firefox, -o- for Opera etc. As with any CSS property, if a browser doesn't support a proprietary extension, it will simply ignore it."

Comment: Well the only thing that isn't supported is background size, you could simply resize the image to the right size and use `background: url('../img/menu_divider.png') no-repeat top left;` and it would work the same in every browser since the dawn of time

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. That was not the whole story after all... I've edited question and answer to reflect that I needed to use the `background-size` properties to maintain the original image size even if replaced with a retina version.

Comment: ... And I also shortened my syntax to follow your suggestions (and removed some, for the question, unnecessary styles). Thank you for your input!